# My c program is not detecting keyboard input

Tags: c

I was trying to do a simple demo on a Stack implementation.

Here's the Stack2.h:

```
#ifndef _STACK_H

struct Node;
typedef int ElementType;
typedef struct Node *PtrToNode;
typedef PtrToNode Stack;

int IsEmpty(Stack S);
Stack CreateStack(void);
void DisposeStack(Stack S);
void MakeEmpty(Stack S);
void Push(ElementType X, Stack S);
ElementType Top(Stack S);
void Pop(Stack S);

#endif
```

Stack2.c:

```
#include "Stack2.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
  ElementType Element;
  PtrToNode Next;
};

int IsEmpty(Stack S) {
  return S->Next == NULL;
}

Stack CreateStack(void) {
  Stack S = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  MakeEmpty(S);
  return S;
}

void DisposeStack(Stack S) {
  MakeEmpty(S);
  free(S);
}

void MakeEmpty(Stack S) {
  while (!IsEmpty(S)) Pop(S);
}

void Push(ElementType X, Stack S) {
  PtrToNode newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  newNode->Element = X;
  newNode->Next = S->Next;
  S->Next = newNode;
}

ElementType Top(Stack S) {
  if (!IsEmpty(S))
    return S->Next->Element;
  return 0;
}

void Pop(Stack S) {
  PtrToNode toPop = S->Next;
  S->Next = S->Next->Next;
  free(toPop);
}
```

tryStack.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Stack2.h"

int main() {
  int num;
  char c;
  Stack nums = CreateStack();
  while ((c = getchar()) != 'x') {
    num = c - '0';
    Push(num, nums);
  }
  while (!IsEmpty(nums)) {
    printf("%d\n", Top(nums));
    Pop(nums);
  }
  DisposeStack(nums);
  return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled them with the line:

```
gcc tryStack.c Stack2.c -o stackDemo
```

It compiled. After typing the command stackDemo, however, it did not respond to any pressing on the keyboard; and the inputs I typed appear on the command prompt only after I terminated the program. Here's the scenario after I've typed 123 and then pressed Control-C:

```
C:\C_code>stackDemo
^C
C:\C_code>123
```

I could not figure out why a simple input via getchar() suddenly fails to work. Could you help take a look? Thank you.

Comment: `CreateStack()` call `MakeEmpty` , `MakeEmpty` call `IsEmpty`, `IsEmpty` use `S->Next` but `S->Next` isn't initialize.

Comment: It turns out this is exactly the case, thank you both! I just replaced the call `MakeEmpty(S); ` in `CreateStack()` with the line `S->Next = NULL;`. Now it pushes properly, except that a random negative int is "embedded" in the stack with each push; for example, if I enter 1, 2, 3,  the values popped out are -38, 3, -38, 2, -38, 1; would you know where this extra -38 comes from?

Comment: Probably, `'\n'`(10)- `'0'`(48) become `-38`.

Comment: 'Tis curious that you show `Stack.h` but use `Stack2.h`.  You should print the characters you read and the values you push as you process them.  Then you'd see where the entries come from.  It is a basic debugging technique: echo the inputs to make sure the program is seeing what you expect it to see.

Comment: I got it now. :-) Oh, the header name is merely a mistype, got it edited now; and thanks for the echo technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the creation of the stack you don't have to create a node, I would only create a pointer to the top node, then set it to NULL so after creation the stack would be empty.

Try this:

Stack.h

```
struct Node;
typedef int ElementType;
typedef struct Node *PtrToNode;
typedef PtrToNode Stack;

int IsEmpty(Stack S);
Stack CreateStack(void);
void DisposeStack(Stack *S);
void MakeEmpty(Stack *S);
void Push(ElementType X, Stack *S);
ElementType Top(Stack S);
void Pop(Stack *S);
```

Stack.c

```
#include "Stack2.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    ElementType Element;
    PtrToNode Next;
};

int IsEmpty(Stack S) {
    return S == NULL;
}

Stack CreateStack(void) {
    Node *S = NULL;
    return S;
}

void DisposeStack(Stack *S) {
    MakeEmpty(S);
    free(*S);
}

void MakeEmpty(Stack *S) {
    while (!IsEmpty(*S)) Pop(S);
}

void Push(ElementType X, Stack *S) {
    PtrToNode newNode = (PtrToNode)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->Element = X;
    newNode->Next = NULL;
    if (IsEmpty(*S))
    {
        *S = newNode;
        return;
    }
    newNode->Next = (*S);
    *S = newNode;
}

ElementType Top(Stack S) {
    if (!IsEmpty(S))
        return S->Element;
    return 0;
}

void Pop(Stack *S) {
    if (IsEmpty(*S)) return;
    PtrToNode toPop = *S;
    *S = (*S)->Next;
    free(toPop);
}
```

tryStack.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Stack2.h"

int main()
{
    int num;
    char c;
    Stack nums = CreateStack();
    while ((c = getchar()) != 'x' && (c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c == '\n')) {
        if (c == '\n') continue;
        num = c - '0';
        Push(num, &nums);
    }
    while (!IsEmpty(nums)) {
        printf("%d\n", Top(nums));
        Pop(&nums);
    }
    DisposeStack(&nums);

    return 0;
}
```

When typing in the numbers you have to ignore '\n', it also good if you check if they are digits or not.

If You stick with your creation function, You can also use this code to get the input without the newline characters:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != 'x' && (c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c == '\n')) 
{
    if (c == '\n') continue;
    num = c - '0';
    Push(num, nums);
}
```